# What is the 'client secret key' in the s3handler example?

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm new to both node, fine uploader and aws.
i'm trying to use the examples  to upload to S3, using the s3handler.js example.
at the top of the file you set up the serverPublicKey, which i understand, the serverSecretKey, which i understand, but there is also a variable for 'clientSecretKey', I don't understand what this variable needs to be? does it have some sort of relationship with the clientpublickey which is used in the frontend javascript? I can't see any explanation of what the 'clientSecretKey' is

Answer (score 3):

When you provision credentials for your uploader, you should have two pairs of keys: server-side, and client-side. The client-side keys should be heavily restricted. Only the most necessary privileges should be assigned to this IAM role/user. The server-side keys can be associated with an administrative-level user, if you prefer. In other words, create a client-side role that is specific to the operations that must be performed client-side by Fine Uploader. You can re-use an existing administrative-level user for all server-side tasks.